# Unable to let puppeteer browse newly collected links reusing the same browser

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I've created a script in `node` in combination with `puppeteer` to scrape the links of different posts from a site's landing page and my script is doing this flawlessly. Although the content of that site are static, I used puppeteer to see how it performs as I'm very new to this.

What I wish to do now is make use of those links to traverse different pages reusing the same browser without scraping anything from the new pages. However, I can't modify my script to reflect the same.

This is my try so far:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false});
    const [page] = await browser.pages();
    await page.goto("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping");
    page.waitFor(".summary");
    const sections = await page.$$(".summary");
    let data = [];
    for (const section of sections) {
        const itemName = await section.$eval(".question-hyperlink", el => el.href);
        data.push(itemName);
    }
    browser.close();
    return data;
})();
```

***How can I rectify my script in order for it to traverse newly collected links reusing the same browser?***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reuse the existing page for the links you have collected and iterate over them before closing the browser:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false});
    const [page] = await browser.pages();
    await page.goto("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping");
    page.waitFor(".summary");
    const sections = await page.$$(".summary");
    let data = [];
    for (const section of sections) {
        const itemName = await section.$eval(".question-hyperlink", el => el.href);
        data.push(itemName);
    }

    // iterate over the URLs
    for (const url of data) {
        await page.goto(url);
    }

    await browser.close();
    return data;
})();
```

#### Alternative with a separate function

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

async function crawlUrls(data, page) {
    for (const url of data) {
        await page.goto(url);
    }
}

(async () => {
    // ...

    // iterate over the URLs
    await crawlUrls(data, page);

    // ...
})();
```

Comment: So damn perfect @Thomas Dondorf!! Is it possible to achive the same from another function instead of doing it within the same function. Will accept it soon. Upvoted already. Thanks.

Comment: @robots.txt Sure, added an alternative, you just have to pass `data` and `page` as argument.